# Please don't hide my profile in the Android App

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, android-app

The current steps to access my profile are the following :

- Click on the menu
- Click my name which brings me to the **Stack Exchange** profile
- Look for the profile I want (sometimes even need to click *see more* to get to the one I'm looking for)
- Click on the almost unclickable link to finally access my profile page.

Per site profiles should be accessible directly on the website that you are visiting or by a quick button in the menu. Anything faster than this process above.

Comment: oh, android app.  [Was about to say...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wq40c.png)